# Problems with Report Variables

Tags: variables, reporting-services

I'm new to SSRS 2012 and have a question about variables.  I have a report that retrieves order and order line information from our database (order #, order line #, item, quantity, etc). I need to add a textbox to the footer of the report that can only be displayed for certain items (i.e. if item # equals "123" then show textbox, otherwise hide it.

I added a report variable called 'ItemExists', and unchecked the read-only flag, and set the default value to 0.

I then added an expression to the textbox on the report footer to show it if variable=1, and to hide it if variable=0.

I'm trying to add a textbox with an expression to the body of the report (same group as where the item # is displayed), but I'm unable to get the report variable to update properly. Here's what I tried:

=IIF((Variables!ItemExists.Value = 0) and (Fields!item.Value = "123"), (Variables!ItemExists.SetValue(1)), Nothing)

This works if the value of the item is 123,  but if the item is not equal to that value, it still sets the ItemExists variable to 1.

The reason I'm checking to see if the variable is equal to 0 is that there may be multiple lines in the report, and if any one of the items is a match, I want the variable to be set to 1.

I'm not sure if I'm way off track here, but if you could provide any assistance on the best way to achieve this, that would be great.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Based on [SSRS Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dd255208.aspx), it notes that `Cannot control when the report processor initializes a variable or evaluates an expression that updates a variable`. Tested on the footer and it displays initial value and does not display updated value. Tested on end of the body and it gets updated with last value from my dataset. Maybe you can try using the variable at the end of the body if it works for your report.

Comment: Thanks t_m. This textbox needs to be the last thing on the report, so it must be displayed in the report footer section (we have other data in the report footer section, and I need to put this below that). I thought the whole point of a report variable versus a group variable is that I could use it anywhere in the report? I did come across the fact that SSRS cannot control when the report processor initializes a variable or evaluates an expression - perhaps this is my problem? If so, how would I be able to pass data from the body of the report to the report footer?

Comment: Based on the information you given and as I am a database guy, I would tend to use another dataset to preprocess the information and in the footer to get first record from the dataset to hide/show. There are other ways that might be better as creating a secondary dataset might be a bit of an over kill but this depends on the amount of data.

Comment: Thanks, good idea. I'll look at modifying the stored procedure to perform the calculation and pass a value to the report, rather than trying to get the report to figure it out.